# Merging list elements with in a list and converting it into string for conversion to decimall

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, binary

```
import numpy as np
txor=np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
def chunker_list(seq, size):
    return (seq[i::size] for i in range(size))
spl2=[]
spl=list(chunker_list(txor, 20))
#spl2=int('1010101',2)
#print(spl)
for i in spl:
    spl1=((i))
    spl2.append(spl1)
#print(spl2)
join=[]
for r in spl2:
    test_list=str(r)
# printing result  
    test_list = [''.join(test_list[ : ])] 
    join.append(test_list)
res=str((join))
```

In this i have generated a data in *spl2* which is like

> [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],  [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],  [1, 1, 0, 0,
>   0],  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],  [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],  [1, 1, 0,
>   1, 0],  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],  [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],  [0, 1,
>   0, 0, 0],  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  [1,
>   0, 0, 1, 0],  [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],  [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], 
>   [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]]

in want these spl2 data in this form

> [['10101'],  ['01101'],  ['00010'],  .........
>   so that i can convert this above data set into decimal. Also write bin to dec code if possible :)

Comment: "Also write bin to dec code if possible :)" => Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I said if possible.. ill do it by myself .'bin to dec'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to tell from your question whether you have already solved the "splitting" part of your problem. You do not need to convert to string to convert to decimal. To answer the second part of your question, here is a simple way to convert your list of binaries into decimals:

```
def bin_to_dec(bins):
    return sum([2 ** p for p, v in enumerate(bins[::-1]) if v])

print(bin_to_dec([0, 0, 0, 1]))
print(bin_to_dec([1, 0, 1]))
print(bin_to_dec([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]))
```

result:

```
1
5
49
```

To apply this to your list of lists above, just do something like this:

```
my_list = [[0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
print([bin_to_dec(bins) for bins in my_list])
```

result:

```
[1, 5, 49]
```

Comment: how m i going to give a whole list in this def function?

Comment: You can just apply it to each element of your list of lists above. I'll edit my answer with how to do this...

Comment: awesome.. thanks alot.. u changed the whole narrative. 
i was trying to convert my list [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],.... to this [['10101'], ['01101'] so that i can write a code 'bin('name',2)' to convert my data .. But this solved my problem to .. Thats why i write " Also write bin to dec code if possible :)"

Answer (score 0):

There are as often many ways to reach the target...
You could do e.g.

```
bin = [''.join([str(i) for i in sub]) for sub in spl2]
dec = [int(b, 2) for b in bin]
```

or with numpy

```
import numpy as np

dec = map(lambda x: np.sum(np.logspace(4, 0, 5, base=2)*x), spl2)
```